# Getting Null Byte using io.StringIO

Tags: python, bytestream

I have the below code

```
stream = io.StringIO(csv_file.stream.read().decode('utf-8-sig'), newline=None) // error is here

reader = csv.DictReader(stream)

list_of_entity = []
line_no, prev_len = 1, 0,

for line in reader:
```

> While executing the above code I got the below error.
>
> ```
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 252862: invalid start byte
> ```

Later to fix this I tried the below.

```
stream = io.StringIO(csv_file.stream.read().decode('unicode_escape'), newline=None)

reader = csv.DictReader(stream)

list_of_entity = []
line_no, prev_len = 1, 0,

for line in reader:// error is here
```

> when i change decode as `unicode_escape` it thrown the error "
>
> ```
> _csv.Error: line contains NULL byte" at above highlighted comment line.
> ```

There is **null byte present in csv**, I want to ignore or replace it.
can anyone help on this.

Comment: It's likely your data is a `bytestream`, use `.BytesIO` instead.

Comment: @stovfl how to use .BytesIO in my code, I have tried replacing                       stream = io.BytesIO(csv_file.stream.read().decode('utf-8'))    but its error saying  
 "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" I think this is not the correct way of using it. can you help me here how can i use BytesIO in my code.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and explain or show **why** do you use `csv_file.stream.read()`? Variable `csv_file` is unknown, which type is it? Do you simple want to read a `CSV` file from disk?